# All c types are still undefined even after using "import ctypes"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

After several failed attempts at using SWIG to import a C++ API into python, I decided to just rewrite all the structs in the header file using ctypes.

```
class Settings(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("f1", c_uint32), 
            ("f2", c_uint16),
            ("f3", c_uint16), 
            ("f4", c_uint*8)]
```

Initially I was using a wildcard import which resulted in an "unable to detect undefined names error" in Spyder(Python2.7).

```
from ctypes import *
```

After reading that using wildcard imports in this manner is bad practice, I tried importing ctypes normally.

```
import ctypes
```

However, all the struct values are still undefined. I haven't found an answer after reading through the ctypes documentation, and am really not sure where to turn from here.

Comment: Did you try accessing them through the `ctypes` namespace?

Comment: eg, ctypes.c_uint32

Comment: I just tried accessing through the namespace `ctypes.c_uint32` etc but now Structure is undefined. What would cause this?

Comment: `ctypes.Structure`.  *Everything* in ctypes will be in the `ctypes` namespace.